# Adding tags to Jupyter notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, papermill

As suggested in the description of the `Jupyter` Miscrosoft extension for Visual Studio Code (VSC), I come here to ask you about support for cell metadata in jupyter notebooks. It seems nothing is currently available for adding cell metadata and, thus, using the `papermill` extension when writing python notebooks with VSC.

The last message in [this 2019 github discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1121), dated 2021-05-28, points to [this other discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1182#issuecomment-840762264) where on 2021-05-13 someone suggested to use [the Jupyter Powertools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.jupyterpowertools).

However, as of today 2021-10-03, that extension seems not to be compatible with either of my VSC versions:

- VSC 1.60.2
- VSC Insiders: 1.61.0

with no updates available for either one of them (using Windows 10).

Is there any way to use `papermill` with VSC? If not, are you aware of any `papermill` alternatives for parameterizing notebooks while using VSC?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find extension [`Jupyter Power Tools`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.jupyterpowertools&ssr=false#overview) that can add tag by click icon `tag+` left beside icon `python`. But it failed in vscode version 1.660

Comment: Did you use it in the Insiders version? Stable is not supported (and you need to launch VSC Insiders via command line).

Answer (score 0):

Update - Jupyter Power Tools is now deprecated and functionality to be included within MSFT's Jupyter PowerToys extension. A tags interface / cell metadata editor does not appear to have been included, but they have an [open issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter-powertoys/issues/48).